# Having problems with indentation in game code

Tags: python, animation, pygame

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

CHARSPEED = 3

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("nq-rotmg.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

FPS = 30
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

pywindow = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('God of the Mad Realm')

background = pygame.image.load("Background.jpg")
background = background.convert()
pywindow.blit(background, (0, 0))
pygame.display.flip()

Assassin = pygame.image.load("Assassin_L.png")

Assassin_R.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
Assassin_L.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
assassinx = 10
assassiny = 10
pygame.key.set_repeat(10, 10)

while True: 
    pywindow.blit(background, (0, 0))

    pywindow.blit(Assassin, (assassinx, assassiny))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if (event.key == K_LEFT):
            Assassin=pygame.image.load('Assassin_L.png')
        elif (event.key == K_RIGHT):  <<<-------------------------------------
            Assassin=pygame.image.load('Assassin_R.png')
        elif (event.key == K_UP):
            Assassin=pygame.image.load('Assassin_L.png')
        elif (event.key == K_DOWN):
            Assassin=pygame.image.load('Assassin_L.png')

keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

if keys_pressed[K_LEFT]:
    assassinx -= CHARSPEED

elif keys_pressed[K_RIGHT]:
    assassinx += CHARSPEED

elif keys_pressed[K_UP]:
    assassiny -= CHARSPEED

elif keys_pressed[K_DOWN]:
    assassiny += CHARSPEED

pygame.display.update()
fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Right where I put the arrow I keep getting a error that states:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Character.py", line 42, in <module>
    elif (event.key == K_RIGHT):
AttributeError: event member not defined
```

I'm sure this is some silly mistake but it's really starting to give me troubles.

Comment: If your code is actually formatted like this, then you just need to put all the elifs on the same indent level as the if, and all the `Assassin = ...` one indent level in.

Comment: oops let me fix the indentation...

Comment: Zzz, do you still get errors when you execute the updated (correctly indented) code?

Comment: Yes, the same exact traceback error.

Comment: Okay, looks like I found the reason for the error, here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/22188551/2689986

Answer (score 2):

You have incorrect indentation yet. The `AttributeError` arises due to the `event` variable not being defined in the correct scope. Your code...

```
for event in pygame.event.get():# <<<--------
    if event.type==QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

if event.type == KEYDOWN:       # <<<--------
    if (event.key == K_LEFT):
```

The `if event.type == KEYDOWN` should be *nested* under the `for` loop for `event` to be defined properly. Hence, the correct code should be,

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type==QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

    if event.type == KEYDOWN:     #  one more indented
        if (event.key == K_LEFT): # corresponding appropriate indent
            Assassin=pygame.image.load('Assassin_L.png')
        elif (event.key == K_RIGHT):
            Assassin=pygame.image.load('Assassin_R.png')
        elif ...
```

Also, all the game execution code should fall under the `while True` block.

```
while True:
    pywindow.blit(background, (0, 0))

    pywindow.blit(Assassin, (assassinx, assassiny))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if (event.key == K_LEFT):
            Assassin=pygame.image.load('Assassin_L.png')
        elif (event.key == K_RIGHT):
            Assassin=pygame.image.load('Assassin_R.png')
        elif (event.key == K_UP):
            Assassin=pygame.image.load('Assassin_L.png')
        elif (event.key == K_DOWN):
            Assassin=pygame.image.load('Assassin_L.png')

    keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys_pressed[K_LEFT]:
        assassinx -= CHARSPEED

    elif keys_pressed[K_RIGHT]:
        assassinx += CHARSPEED

    elif keys_pressed[K_UP]:
        assassiny -= CHARSPEED

    elif keys_pressed[K_DOWN]:
        assassiny += CHARSPEED

    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Oh, did you add the corresponding lines? I wrongly showed an `if` without it's code block. Updating.

Comment: Yes I did, the only problem is the character is no longer appearing. I am not sure if I blitted wrong or what...

Comment: Actually, you didn't even blit the characters. Do that at the end of the `if event.type == KEY_DOWN` block.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this? Once the user presses `KEYDOWN`, you want to check if it's `K_LEFT`, `K_RIGHT`, `K_UP`, or `K_DOWN`, so those if and elif statements should be at the same indentation.

```
if event.type == KEYDOWN:
    if (event.key == K_LEFT):
        Assassin=pygame.image.load('Assassin_L.png')
    elif (event.key == K_RIGHT):
        Assassin=pygame.image.load('Assassin_R.png')
    elif (event.key == K_UP):
        Assassin=pygame.image.load('Assassin_L.png')
    elif (event.key == K_DOWN):
        Assassin=pygame.image.load('Assassin_L.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have used TABs to indent those two lines (at least in the version you posted here)

Find the TABs, delete them and replace with spaces.

Some editors will let you set preferences to use the TAB key to insert spaces instead of TAB characters. That can help you avoid this type of problem

Comment: Which two lines? Also, aren't TAB's four spaces?

Comment: @Dominico909, no Python's tabstops are at 8 characters. The rules for mixing TABs and SPACEs are complicated to explain. It's best just not to use TABs for indenting

Comment: @Dominico909, The `if event.type == KEYDOWN:
    if (event.key == K_LEFT):` are the lines that I saw with TABs